# Autocomplete does not work in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

When doing an `ajax`-request for an `autocomplete` I get an `undefined` error:

**View**:

```
 <input type="text" name="" id="search"> 
 <ul>
    <div id="result"></div>
 </ul>
```

**Javascript**:

```
$("#search").autocomplete({
      minLength: 1,
      source: 
      function(req, add){
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/ajaxPro",
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                data: req,
                success: function(data){
                    if(data.response =="true"){
                        add(data.message);
                    }
                },
           });
       },
       select: function(event, ui) {
           $("#result").append(
               "<li>"+ ui.item.value + "</li>"
           );                  
       },      
});
```

**Controller**:

```
  public function ajaxPro()
  {
       $term = $this->input->get('term');

       $this->db->like('business_name', $term);
     
       $data = $this->db->get("user_table")->result();
       header('Content-Type: application/json');
       echo json_encode($data);
  }
```

**Database**:
[this is the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaRV2.jpg)

There is no error in the console, Data is showing the network preview but it is not showing on the view page I do not know what the problem is Can you help

**The Problem**:

> Return value: undefined

Comment: I think `"true"` is validating as string while data.response has a true flag (boolean)

Comment: How to Solve this?

Comment: Try by changing this line `if(data.response ==true){`

Comment: i tried but its not working

Comment: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]                     "This is how the values in the data are displayed when displayed in the Alert window"

Comment: Return value: undefined this is the problem plz help me

Comment: Can you send complete file and db SQL file to me at ping@naveedramzan.com I will make it workable and send to you

Comment: @NaveedRamzan Please stay on the platform! So everyone can benefit from your solution!

Comment: I am available and resolved the issue @31ITSolutionsThiruvalla Please confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Change your **Controller** code to something like this:

```
public function ajaxPro()
{
    $term = $this->input->get('term');

    $this->db->like('business_name', $term);
     
    $data = $this->db->get("user_table")->result();
    
    $ajaxData = array();
    foreach($data as $row) {
        $ajaxData[] = array(            // Set "label"+"value" for autocomplete for each result
            'label' => $row['name'],    // <- change this to your column name
            'value' => $row['id']       // <- this should be the ID-Value
        );
    }
    
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(
        'status' => 'success',
        'data' => $ajaxData
    );
}
```

And your **ajax success callback**:

```
success: function(r){
    if(typeof r.status != "undefined" && r.status == "success"){
        response(r.data);  // lets autocomplete build response list
    } else {
        console.log(r);   // error occured
    }
},
```

*(I changed your response variable from `data` to `r` to clearify this is not just the actual data, but a response in a variable that can contain much more than just the data from your sql-find result. It usually holds data exactly in the format you give in `json_encode()` )*

---

**Explanation:**

In this line:

```
if(data.response =="true"){
```

You are asking for a value/key `response` that does not exist.

---

**Tips on Debugging and Troubleshooting:**

To see what your ajax-response look like, you can open the Dev-Tools in your Browser (ususally `F12` and go to the Tab that shows your network requests. There you can find your ajax-request and see the headers you sent and the final response.

Furthermore if you add `debugger;` in this line, you can debug your javascript and see all variables available in the current scope:

```
success: function(r){
    debugger; // this is a breakpoint equivalent and will halt your code execution when dev tools are open!
```